# Java add time to keyReleased?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener, enter

I am capturing each keyPress within a *JTextArea* and sending it off to the chatserver to let the person on the other end know that the user is typing.

Currently I got this:

```
sm.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            sendMsg(sm.getText(), "message", atName);
            sm.setText(null);
        } else { // Typing
            sendMsg("", "typing", atName);
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine it sends `sendMsg("", "typing", atName);` on each keypress except for <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However this is slowing down the server a bit.

How could i add a timer or something to this in order not to send exactly all keypresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a flag which would indicate if the user was typing. Then you could only send one "typing" message, the first time they press a key.

```
boolean isTyping = false;

sm.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            sendMsg(sm.getText(), "message", atName);
            sm.setText(null);
            isTyping = false;
        } else { // Typing
            if (isTyping) {
                if (sm.getText().length() == 0) {
                    isTyping = false;
                    // Send a message indicating the user has stopped typing
                    sendMsg("", "stopTyping", atName); //Customize the message type here, may need to adjust the server
                }
            } else {
                isTyping = true;
                sendMsg("", "typing", atName);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How so? It sends a single "typing" message when the user begins typing, and waits until they send the message before resetting the flag.

Comment: Sorry, my bad; I was reading too fast. On the opposite, it only sends one message at all. What if the user spends 5 minutes typing (or if it ends typing and does not send)? Usually in chat boxes you see the "now is typing/now is not typing" info to be updated more often than that.

Comment: Does the "is typing" info need to be updated more often? If the user is still typing, I would expect it to continue to say "is typing". But if the user erases their message, it should stop, I agree.

Comment: Dident think of this only 1 msg being sent is awesome :) THanks!

Comment: If you just trust in a single message, you will not know if a user closes the app or loses connection. Everyone else will be kept seeing "is typing" forever.

Comment: Updated the code, now it allows the user to cancel "typing" by erasing their message. Note: this may require a change to the server.

Comment: @SJuan76 If the connection is lost, the server could take responsibility, and remove the "is typing" status.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new thread that sends a message once per `x` seconds if a user is typing.

```
public void Updater implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean typing;        

    public void typing() {
        typing = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (typing) {
                 sendMsg(...);
                 typing = false;
            }
            Thread.sleep(x * 1000); // x - seconds
        }
    }
}
```

Then call `updater.typing()` whenever key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a separate thread that will be in charge of communicating with the server (this also helps avoiding GUI freezes if the server is slow answering).

2) The listener just writes to a queue indicating the user action (the level of detail is up to you). In the simplest case, it just sets a flag.

3) Every x seconds, the thread reads the queue/flag, resets it and sends the message (if needed).

Alternatively, set a date attribute in your listener, and every time you send a message the current time is stored. Every time an event arrives, if there has not passed enough time, it simply gets ignored. Simpler, but less "precise". Also, it will have "GUI frozen" issues if the server is slow answering.

Comment: Implemented naïvely, this will send as many messages as before, just in bursts.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel the idea is that you only send one message no matter how many events are in the queue (the idea of the queue is for generalization and allow for different messages; if you only have a message, you can do with a flag).

Answer (score 0):

Add a member variable of type `long` to the listener (called `lastSent` for instance), in `keyReleased` compute the difference between `System.currentTimeInMillis()` and the saved value and only send when the difference is greater than your threshold. Remember to set `lastSent` whenever you actually send something.